# ¿Como detener peticiones get echas con Volley dentro de los fragmentos de un Menu Drawer?

Tags: android

Hola amigos tengo una duda. Tengo un menu Drawer en el cual utilizo diversos fragments para consultar un servicio de internet que esta consumida con volley pero al cambiar de fragment sin que alla terminado de cargar esa vista se colapsa la aplicacion.

anexo codigo

Codigo de llama a los fragments desde el menu drawer

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_resumen) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new ResumenFragment()).commit();
            setTitle("Resumen");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_perfil) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            setTitle("Perfil");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_asignadas) {

            //startActivity(new Intent(this, TerminarEnvioActivity.class));

            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new AsignadasFragment()).commit();
            setTitle("Asignadas");

            // Toast.makeText(context, "Free", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_historial) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new HistorialFragment()).commit();
            setTitle("Historial");
```

Codigo que uso en cada fragment para llamar a mi servicio con Volley

```
private void cargarDatos()
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String urlBASE="https://" + UrlRemote.baseDebug + UrlRemote.EndPointProfile;

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver_id",driver_id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", driver_id));
        NameValuePair Dato = SecurityUtils.getSignature(urlBASE, params);

        try {
            url2 = new URL(urlBASE + UrlRemote.getQuery(params));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String Firma = String.valueOf(Dato);

        String URLFINAL = url2+"&"+Firma;


        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLFINAL, null,this,this);
                jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(myRetryPolicy());
                VolleySingleton.getInstance(thiscontext).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No se puede optener los datos "+ error , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("error", error.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        jsonObject = response.optJSONObject("Driver");
        profile.setBonus(jsonObject.optString("bonus"));
        profile.setCommissions(jsonObject.optString("commissions"));
        profile.setMonth(jsonObject.optString("month"));
        profile.setDriver_name(jsonObject.optString("Driver_name"));
        profile.setTotal(jsonObject.optString("total"));
        profile.setCycle(jsonObject.optString("cycle"));
        profile.setDriver_user(jsonObject.optString("Driver_user"));
        profile.setDriver_telephone(jsonObject.optString("Driver_telephone"));
        profile.setDriver_photo_url(jsonObject.optString("Driver_photo_url"));
        profile.setDiscounts(jsonObject.optString("discounts"));
        profile.setDriver_ranking(jsonObject.optString("Driver_ranking"));
        profile.setDairy(jsonObject.optString("dairy"));
        profile.setBalance(jsonObject.optString("balance"));
        profile.setDriver_plate(jsonObject.optString("Driver_plate"));
        profile.setPending(jsonObject.optString("pending"));


        //Vaciar los datos en los elementos
        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(profile.getDriver_photo_url())
                .into(circleImageView);
        nameDriver.setText(profile.getDriver_name().toString());
        userDriver.setText(profile.getDriver_user().toString());
        telefonoDriver.setText(profile.getDriver_telephone().toString());
        plateDriver.setText(profile.getDriver_plate().toString());
        ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(profile.getDriver_ranking()));

        //Vacias datos de sueldos del perfil
        textSueldo.setText(profile.getBalance().toString());
        textComisiones.setText(profile.getCommissions().toString());
        textBonos.setText(profile.getBonus());
        textDescuentos.setText(profile.getDiscounts());
        textPendientesPago.setText(profile.getPending());
        textTotal.setText(profile.getTotal());
        textEnviosDiarios.setText(profile.getDairy());
        textEnviosQuincenales.setText(profile.getCycle());
        textEnviosMensuales.setText(profile.getMonth());


    }
```

espero y me puedan ayudar el error que obtengo es:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.app99minutos.app99minutos.Views.ResumenFragment$3.onErrorResponse(ResumenFragment.java:258)

Cada vez que cambio de `Fragment` se queda realizando la petición anterior pero como no tiene donde imprimir colapsa

Comment: y que muestra el Logcat?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference                     at com.app99minutos.app99minutos.Views.ResumenFragment$3.onErrorResponse(ResumenFragment.java:258)
Cada vez que cambio de fragment se queda realizando la peticion anterior pero como no tiene donde imprimir colapsa

Comment: @AlfredoHernández la linea 25 de tu Fragment ResumenFragment es el Toast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad no es problema el realizar varias peticiones, el problema es que no debes imprimir el valor de `error` que  se recibe dentro de `onErrorResponse()`, el valor de `error`, es del tipo `VolleyError`, aquí debes manejar tus propios mensajes, por ejemplo:

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Sin Conexión", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error fallo al autenticar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error servidor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de Red", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Parseo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```